# Связь двух Combobox в DataGrid/ListBox, реализация категории и подкатегории в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, фильтр

Есть список категорий и подкатегорий, характеризующий аппарат. Например, двигатель может быть электрическим, внутреннего сгорания, но никак не центробежный, так как это подкатегория насоса.

Категории реализованы в виде класса CategoryItem

```
public class CategoryItem
{
    public CategoryItem(string Category, string Subcategory)
    {
        this.Category = Category;
        this.Subcategory = Subcategory;
    }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string Subcategory { get; set; }
}
```

Список стандартных сочетаний категорий представлен в виде массива

```
CategoryTemplateList = new CategoryItem[]
{
    new CategoryItem("Привод", "Электродвигатель"),
    new CategoryItem("Привод", "Двигатель внутреннего сгорания"),
    new CategoryItem("Насос", "Центробежный"),
    new CategoryItem("Насос", "Вакуумный водокольцевой"),
    new CategoryItem("Генератор", "Синхронный"),
    new CategoryItem("Шланговый барабан", "С автонамотчиком"),
    new CategoryItem("Форсунок", "Очистной"),
    new CategoryItem("Форсунок", "Каналопромывочный"),
};
```

В классе окна сочетания и коллекция для хранения свойств аппарата хранятся в виде массива CategoryItem и ObservableCollection

```
    public CategoryItem[] CategoryTemplateList { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<CategoryItem> CurrentList = new ObservableCollection<CategoryItem>();
```

Разметка xaml окна хранит в себе ListBox с шаблоном с двумя ComboBox

```
<ListBox x:Name="DisplayedList">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ComboBox Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CategoryTemplateList,Mode=OneTime,ElementName=CurrentWindow}" Text="{Binding Path=Category,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" DisplayMemberPath="Category"/>
                <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CategoryTemplateList,Mode=OneTime,ElementName=CurrentWindow}" Text="{Binding Path=Subcategory,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" DisplayMemberPath="Subcategory"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Выпадающие списки работают, но мне не понятно, как сделать фильтрацию элементов в случае, когда ComboBox ов много и они находятся в шаблоне
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Пытался сделать через CollectionViewSource, но мне не удалось получить для сравнения выбранную из первого ComboBox строку с категорией, поэтому не допустить подкатегории не удалось.

Как можно реализовать фильтрацию элементов в ComboBox в шаблоне исходя из данных другого элемента в нём же?

Comment: проще всего как мне кажется будет хранить группы. То есть класс `public class Category
{
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<string> SubCategory { get; set; }
}` и первый ComboBox привязывать к `ObservableCollection<Category>`, а второй к `{Binding cmb1.SelectedItem.SubCategory}`

Comment: @FoggyFinder А как мы перебандим второй комбобокс используя XAML? Это не чистое решение

Comment: @ТрипольскийПётр Вся работа по фильтрации должна происходить в коде, а не в интерфейсе. У тебя должно быть в модели два списка и одно int свойство: `ObservableCollection<string> Category`, `ObservableCollection<string> SubCategory` и `SelectedIndex`. Каждый `ComboBox` должен байндиться к своему списку, а первый к int свойству. Когда в первом списке выбирается какой-то элемент, то ты в коде получаешь его индекс и там уже заполняешь второй список.

Comment: @John модель вынесена в Shared Project, не хотелось бы городить костыли для WPF и тащить на другие платформы

Comment: @John А как ты из кода доберешься до второго комбобокса? Можно подцепиться к событию выбора нового элемента первого и как-то пытаться работать с принимаемым в параметры Object sender для получения второго, но код будет совсем не универсальный. Программа жахнется, если другой разработчик изменит модель. Должен быть способ настроить фильтрацию штатными средствами для данного случая

Comment: Что значит штатными средствами? На все ваши случаи штатных средств не напасёшься. Вообще не понятно, у вас одна коллекция и выбираете вы из нее, зачем вам 2 ComboBox, используйте один, задайте в нем просто `ItemTemplate`

Comment: @АндрейNOP В wpf есть возможность фильтровать коллекции используя ICollectionView. Вопрос в том, как подцепить экземпляр этого интерфейса из элемента ListBox. Я пытался использовать, но не смог получить текущий элемент CategoryItem для сравнения. Про фильтрацию смотрел тут: https://wpftutorial.net/DataViews.html#filtering

Comment: Я знаю про фильтрацию, но она недоступна из разметки

Comment: я показал Binding для второго `comboBox`

Answer (score 0):

укажи в элементе

```
ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=ComboBox1, Path=SelectedItem, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource ConverterItemSource}}"
```

создай новый конвертор, и пропиши его в Window.Resources

```
public class ConverterItemSourсe : System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return null;


        return (from CategoryItem item in CategoryTemplateList where item.Category == ((CategoryItem)value).Category select item).ToList();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Думаю поможет.

Comment: Конвертер в данном случае не сработает: он преобразует значения только один раз и так как мы работаем в шаблоне невозможно будет вызвать View.Refresh() у CollectionViewSource второго ComboBox

Comment: У Вас значение первого ComboBox будет меняться и по ходу дела должно меняться наполнение второго. Вы пробовали данный вариант реализовать?